# python client api behind proxy

Tags: python, google-api-python-client

I have my proxy setup in my environment and python does see it.  If I do os.environ['http_proxy'], I do see the proxy specified (and all of my other applications use it).

However, when I try to use the python google client api (calendar), it appears it isn't being used even though a rough inspection indicates the default http instance is using proxy from environment.

```
 service, flags = sample_tools.init(
        argv, 'calendar', 'v3', __doc__, __file__,
        scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'
    )
```

Inside that call, I see it is doing:

```
http = credentials.authorize(http = httplib2.Http())
```

Which ultimately is doing:

```
def __init__(self, cache=None, timeout=None,
                 proxy_info=proxy_info_from_environment,
                 ca_certs=None, disable_ssl_certificate_validation=False):
```

Shouldn't the proxy_info_from_environment be picking it up?  On a side note, when I added a breakpoint inside that function, it was never hit.  Obviously, that is the reason I'm not getting it set up with the proxy, but it should be, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google API + proxy + httplib2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36784437/google-api-proxy-httplib2)